# Xcode file permission issue

Tags: ios, xcode

I updated my MacOS to **Catalina**, after that I am getting error reading issue in one project only. Check below image

> [image]

When I try to open the file in my xcode, I got below error.

> [image]

If I opened the same file from finder, then it opens the same file in xcode successfully. And issue is shifted to other file. I tried 7-8 times and it continuously coming from one file to another.

---

**Already tried**

1. Open backup project and still getting same issue.
2. Tried with changing the folder directory, like copied project to desktop, but still getting issue
3. Cleaned and build the project,
4. Restart my mac.

---

**Note:** I am getting issue in one project and rest of my projects are working file.

Is there any one time solution for this issue?

Comment: Did you give Xcode permission to access the Desktop folder? Check in System Preferences, Security & Privacy

Comment: @Dimitrie-TomaFurdui, I didn't found Security and privacy option in preferences. Please [Check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO5zy.png)

Comment: Not in Xcode settings, in System Preferences

Comment: Im getting issue only in one project only. rest of projects are working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message can occur (somewhat misleadingly) if Xcode does not have permissions to access your Documents folder, and your project references a file that is not located within the same folder path as the project file.

The error message is misleading because the issue is not "you" (a user) lacking permission to view the file.  The issue is that Xcode doesn't have permission to access the location of the file.

To resolve, go to System Preferences, Security & Privacy, Files and Folders, and enable Xcode to access the Documents folder.  (Current as of MacOS 10.15.4 and Xcode 11.4.1)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the permission from the Finder, right click on that file, goto info and then on bottom under sharing and permission change the privilege to read and write against your username. This might solve your issue.

[image: Check here]

Comment: Hi, It have already same permissions -> [Check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuK4C.png)

Comment: try in a different mac, check if the problem persisting only on your mac or every mac.

Comment: Yeah it is varying, I already checked it. Another mac it is working file while same working project not working in my mac.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the permission if not already done.
Enter the following in your terminal:

> sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/macmini1/Desktop/Classes

It will ask for your password and then you will good to go.

Comment: Can I change permission for main project folder so that all subfolders and files will be reflected.

Comment: Yes you can. in fact this -R is doing so :)

Comment: I tried this, but getting same error :( . Don't know why it is only happening with one project only. Even I took new repo of project (project is old and never been pushed and made any changes) and issue is over there too.

Comment: Could you share your file's info from get info option?